# objective-C syntax beginner question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to use the appRecord.myName in the viewDidLoad,
when i put it there it error up that appRecord is undeclared, how to declare it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"pilotWay";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    int nodeCount = [self.entries count];

    if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                           reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];   
            cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"load";

        return cell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    if (nodeCount > 0)
    {
        AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.myName;             
        cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.appName;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. It looks like you have a unique AppRecord object for each row in your table. If so, what's the point of declaring an AppRecord in the viewDidLoad method? That method will be called once when your viewController class is loaded, while the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called many times as your cells are loaded.

Comment: Let's not tag Objective-C questions as C. We have enough confusion about C and C++ as it is without throwing in a third language using that tag.

Comment: i just want to use the value of myName (an NSString object that declared in a different class called AppRecord) in another method that get called from viewDidLoad, how?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `#import "AppRecord.h"` at the top of that file?

Comment: yes, everything works fine in the class, but if i want to use the appRecord.myName in the viewDidLoad for another purpose the appRecord is yet been define, how to define it?

Answer (score -1):

It appears that `appRecord` is declared (`=` does that). Perhaps you need to cast it, though: `(AppRecord *)[self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`. Whatever you do, to check whether `appRecord` exists, try the following and run:

```
NSLog(@"appRecord: %@", appRecord);
```

You should get a description of the object `appRecord` with a memory address if it exists. Let me know if any of this helps, or if you need further explanation.

Comment: The class isn't declared anywhere, which I imagine is what his problem is.

Comment: thanks for the respond!  
appRecord declared in a method that doesn't get called from the viewDidLoad so appRecord is still undefined.

Comment: the class is declared, everything works fine in the class, but if i want to use the appRecord.myName in the viewDidLoad for another purpose the appRecord is yet been define, how to define it?